# Using the parameter "LATEST' while building the project does not work with "mvn clean install"

Tags: s4sdk

If we use the 'LATEST' parameter when generating the project, the command 'mvn clean install' errors out. Should this parameter be used or should the latest version be provided in the command?

```
mvn archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.archetypes" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=scp-cf-tomee" **"-DarchetypeVersion=LATEST**" "-DgroupId=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples" "-DartifactId=my-app" "-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Error is

```
Error:
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/5.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-bom-5.1.1.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:5.1.1.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): proxy.myproxy.corp @ com.sap.cloud.s4hana:sdk-bom:2.7.1-SNAPSHOT, C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.m2\repository\com\sap\cloud\s4hana\sdk-bom\2.7.1-SNAPSHOT\sdk-bom-2.7.1-SNAPSHOT.pom, line 994, column 25
 @[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR][ERROR]   The project com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples:address-manager1:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\my-app\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:5.1.1.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): proxy.wdf.sap.corp @ com.sap.cloud.s4hana:sdk-bom:2.7.1-SNAPSHOT, C:\Users\xxxxxx\.m2\repository\com\sap\cloud\s4hana\sdk-bom\2.7.1-SNAPSHOT\sdk-bom-2.7.1-SNAPSHOT.pom, line 994, column 25: Unknown host proxy.myproxy.corp -> [Help 2]
[ERROR][ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR][ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Answer (score 1):

The version 2.7.1-SNAPSHOT in not a released version. It is not available externally (maven-central). So, you cannot download it from maven central. However, 2.6.1 is available. That is why it works.

Please try with RELEASE instead of LATEST or better use released versions directly.

Please also check that settings.xml does not point to an internal snapshot nexus server and delete the local repository in your .m2 directory.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This is what I thought. Using 'RELEASE' instead of 'LATEST' makes more sense. May be we can update the same in the blog as well..  https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/21/step-2-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-helloworld-on-scp-classic/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your network configuration?

I can see a proxy and unknown host error in the log.

Comment: I think the proxy is not an issue here. The reason being, if I give the latest release version, for example, 2.6.1 instead of parameter 'LATEST', mvn clean install does not error out and it builds the project successfully.